# showing the cursor in my editText search view

Tags: java, android, focus

I have the following xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/theTitleBar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/text_area_search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:textSize="14dp" >
        <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/speechRecognition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/recording_bt_crop_idle"
        android:onClick="speechRecognitionClicked"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the soft-keyboard is open the moment the activity is on.

how can i force the text cursor appear and blink?

nowadays it doesn't appear even after the user clicks in this editText.

I have added `<requestFocus />` but it didn't help

this is my code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (type==AddressItem.FAVORITE_ITEM_EMPTY) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                searchBox.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.showSoftInput(searchBox, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"`

Comment: Have you tried this programmatically? I have had success this way: `EditText input = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.searchBox); input.RequestFocus ();`

Comment: tried, but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/my_cursor"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try, To show cursor in editText, just use

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
android:textColor="@color/someColor"
```

PS: Color is an optional but incase if you want to change color of cursor you can change it.

Comment: android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/my_cursor"

Answer (score -1):

Try 
   searchBox.setSelection(0);

Comment: requestFocus is needed?

Comment: Yes keep it there as well.

Comment: didnt help. please see my updte

Comment: Try searchBox.setSelection(0);